# MySQL: is there any MySQL workaround for this simple view subquery?

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

I know I can't do a subquery inside a from clause for a view in MySQL. (error 1349)

Is there any workaround for this simple statement.

```
CREATE VIEW view as 
   SELECT * FROM
   (
       SELECT Credits.ID,Credits,Bonus 
       FROM Credits,Bonus 
       WHERE Credits.ID = Bonus.ID
       ORDER BY Credits.Date DESC, Bonus.Date DESC
   ) as tmp
   GROUP BY ID
```

This is that I want to get

`ID  Credits Bonus
1   1300    2
2   23  40
3   3045    134`

---

#### Solved

I resolved this with a correlative sql query.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? Can you please post some sample data and some expected output?

Comment: just a thought but probably not best way to do it. You can create a view using an existing view. In other words, create a view from your subquery and then create a view using that view in your FROM clause. this will probably degrade your performance though.

Comment: I resolved this with a correlative sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  First, write the query correctly.  Your query is depending on the `order by` actually working in the subquery, although MySQL doesn't guarantee this.

I am speculating that you want the records from `credits` along with the most recent `bonus` record.  Without sample data, desired results, and data layouts, it can be hard to interpret queries.

Instead, you should use `not exists`:

```
CREATE VIEW view as 
    select c.ID, c.Credits, b.Bonus
    from credits c join
         bonus b
         on c.id = b.id
    where not exists (select 1
                      from bonus b2
                      where b2.id = b.id and b2.date > b.date
                     );
```

Subqueries are allowed in the `where` (and `select` clauses).